# Building a query that is most efficiently finds If a range of dates is in an interval?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, intervals

Overlap exists between DateRange1 and DateRange2

```
DateRange1:        |-----------|
DateRange2:                |-------|
```

Overlap does not exist between DateRange3 and DateRange4

```
DateRange3:    |------|
DateRange4:                 |-------|
```

I have a query that checks if there is an overlap, but it's a little hairy.  It involves checking each DateRange border and uses a lot of <'s and >'s.

I was wondering if you could say like, if DateRange1.Union(DateRange2) != null, do stuff. 
Just something to make my code more readable and less hairy.

Thanks!

Comment: And the connection between the Title and the actual question is ....

Comment: Why don't you implement a `bool Intersects(other)` method?

Comment: I have found an implementation (http://noticeablydifferent.com/CodeSamples/DateRange.aspx) that already does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add a IncludedDates property (`IEnumerable<DateTime>`), it should be pretty easy.

```
DateRange1.IncludedDates.Intersect(DateRange2.IncludedDates).Any()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd create an extension method:

```
public static bool OverlappedTo(this DateRange range1, DateRange range2)
{
    return range1.OverlappedTo(range2.Start, range2.End);
}

// Just an example, implement as you prefer...
public bool OverlappedTo(this DateRange range1, DateRange range2)
{
    var duration1 = range1.End - range1.Start;
    var duration2 = range2.End - range2.Start;

    var minStart = range1.Start < range2.Start ? range1.Start : range2.Start;
    var maxEnd = range1.End > range2.End ? range1.End : range2.End;

    var totalDuration = maxEnd - minStart;

    // if the sum of the 2 durations is less than 
    // the total duration --> overlapped
    return duration1 + duration2 < totalDuration;
}
```

Usage:

```
bool overlapped = range1.OverlappedTo(range2);
```

**P.S.**

My `DateRange` class resemble to this:
(perhaps you have another implementation)

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime End { get; private set; }

    public DateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
(according to the comments)

```
var outSideRange = new DateRange(start, end);

var filteredRows = 
dt.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(x => outSideRange.OverlappedTo(x.Field<DateTime>("StartCol"),
                                        x.Field<DateTime>("EndCol")));
```

Comment: Why don't you simply do `maxStart <= minEnd`?

Comment: @Jaroslav: yes, that's probably easier, btw mine was just an example, the problem is not the implementation but how to reduce the length/ improve the readability of the code, and IMO the only way is creating an ad hoc method.

Comment: @digEmAll: Yeah, I got that. I just thought you used such a long algorithm on purpose...

Comment: How would I implement this in a linq query?  var res = db.table.where(a=> OverlappedTo) ... I'm lost

Comment: @sooprise: we need an example of what you exactly have, is something similar to a list of ranges ?

Comment: digEmAll, Ok, I have a aStart, aEnd, outside of my linq query, and from the database I have dStart, dEnd.  So one interval lives in my code, and I'm checking it against date ranges in a database.  I hope that clears things up, thanks.

Comment: @sooprise: And you want all the rows that are overlapped to your outside range, right ?

Comment: I can get it working in query syntax (from a in db.Table where), but I want the whole thing in extension method syntax (db.table.where())

Comment: Digemall, I finished writing the overlapping logic, all I need to know is how to implement it in an extension method style query. Thank you much!

Comment: My biggest problem lies here: var res = db.table.where(a=> ) //I don't know how to extract field names under the table using a lambda expression while using my overlapping method.

Comment: OOps, I guess my query style syntax implementation didnt work.  Method 'Boolean DatesOverlap(...)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: Oh, is LINQ2SQL then ?? I thought it was LINQ 2 Objects over a datatable O_O... you should use the correct tag...